# Interfaces on c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface, abstract, chess

I wanted to ask you which version is better to use.
I am talking about de inheritance of the pawn.
in the first example i have a double inheritance, in the second i have just one and i want to know which version is better to use.

Look at the class Pawn.
first:

```
class AbstractPiece
{
protected:
    std::string name;
    PieceColor pieceColor;
    Square currentSquare;
    char _buff[50];
public:
    AbstractPiece(PieceColor _pieceColor);
     std::string getName();
     PieceColor getPieceColor();
    Square getCurrentSquare();
     void setCurrentSquare(Square _currentSquare);

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &c, AbstractPiece &p);

};

class InterfaceMovable
{
public:
    virtual std::list<Location> getValidMoves(Board board)=0;
    virtual void makeMove(Square square)=0;

};

class Pawn : public AbstractPiece, public InterfaceMovable
{
public:
    Pawn(PieceColor _pieceColor);
    std::list<Location> getValidMoves(Board board);
    void makeMove(Square square);

};
```

or like this:

```
class AbstractPiece
{
protected:
    std::string name;
    PieceColor pieceColor;
    Square currentSquare;
    char _buff[50];
public:
    AbstractPiece(PieceColor _pieceColor);
     std::string getName();
     PieceColor getPieceColor();
    Square getCurrentSquare();
     void setCurrentSquare(Square _currentSquare);
     virtual std::list<Location> getValidMoves(Board board)=0;
    virtual void makeMove(Square square)=0;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &c, AbstractPiece &p);

};


class Pawn : public AbstractPiece
{
public:
    Pawn(PieceColor _pieceColor);
    std::list<Location> getValidMoves(Board board);
    void makeMove(Square square);

};
```

Comment: Both are flawed: you will not be able to model *en passant* with this structure as that depends on the previous move of the opponent. Unless that's somehow encapsulated into `Board`.

Comment: That depends on whether any `AbstractPiece` should logically be movable. If so, why not consider inheriting `AbstractPiece` from `InterfaceMovable`?

Comment: I thought about that too

Comment: how would u do it @Bathsheba ?

Comment: You're not going to like me for saying this, but apart from the user interface, the best chess programs seem to be written in procedural languages like C. Perhaps I'm just old-fashioned but I find that object oriented concepts get in the way of the workings of a chess program. If you're serious about building a chess program, there are plenty of books out there, along with open source projects too.

Comment: I understand what are you saying, but we have to do a app with oop in c++ for the university. I chose chess because it;s harder than the other .

Comment: Why does `InterfaceMovable` exist? Do you envision any chess pieces that are not movable, or something that is movable but not a chess piece?

Comment: @Bathsheba "you will not be able to model en passant with this structure as that depends on the previous move of the opponent" yes but that might simply be solved via an extension, for instance via a further (game-/board) state parameter to the interface functions.